# Automate Version Validation MS Master Data

Tags: sql-server, powershell, master-data-services

Our Company has a Powershell Script in place to update a staging table containing detailed information about all active and non-active servers from a csv file.

The staging table is then uploaded to MS Master Data Services 2012 Database through sql procedure, all in the same script.

However, when we access the Master Data through our web server we notice that all updates need validation.

It seems that the only way to proceed is to manually validate and commit all changes.

Does anyone know if it is possible through Powershell?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Powershell developer, but from what I understand here [How to Call a WCF Service from Windows PowerShell](http://www.dispatchertimer.com/wcf/calling-a-wcf-service-from-windows-powershell/) you should be able to call the MS MDS API([Service.ValidationProcess Method (ValidationProcessRequest)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.masterdataservices.services.service.validationprocess(v=sql.120).aspx)) to apply validation programmatically.